# atom + mocha on windows = spawn mocha ENOENT

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, atom-editor

My goal is to run mocha unit tests by Atom, which is installed on Windows and also my src code resides. this should work independently from my Meteor App which is running on a different (Linux) machine.

Basically my setup is like this:

I have my repo and sourcecode:

```
c:\Users\Me\repos\meteor
```

My tests are inside:

```
c:\Users\Me\repos\meteor\tests
```

I have Node:

```
 c:\Program Files\nodejs
```

installed with `"npm i -g mocha --save-dev"`

And i try to use this package https://github.com/Tabcorp/atom-mocha-test-runner but i can switch to another package if necessary.

What I've tried so far:

I edited my settings for the atom-mocha-test-runner:

[image]

```
Mocha command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\mocha\.bin\mocha
Mocha command: C:\Program Files\nodejs\npm mocha
```

But each time i try to run my test via dropdown menu (Run Mocha Test), i get this error:

```
Mocha Test Results:

Node binary:    C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
Root folder:    C:\Source\Repos
Mocha command:  undefined
Path to mocha:  mocha
Debug-Mode:     false
Test file:      tests\unit\first.js
Selected test:  should return url

Failed to run Mocha
spawn mocha ENOENT
```

Anyone know what i miss or do wrong?

Comment: In the `mocha-test-runner` settings, there's a checkbox labeled `Show Context Information`. It might be helpful if you checked that, ran the command, and then shared with us the results.

Comment: @HollandWilson done, it seems like there's a problem with the mocha command, but why?

Comment: To me it seems like there's a problem with `mochaCommand`. I found the file where the package assembles the command string (https://github.com/Tabcorp/atom-mocha-test-runner/blob/master/lib/context.coffee#L22) and where the context gets displayed (https://github.com/Tabcorp/atom-mocha-test-runner/blob/master/lib/mocha-test-runner.coffee#L90) and `mochaCommand` should not be turning up undefined as far as I can tell. And yes, I'm having the same issue with the same context output when I try to test on my machine, so it's definitely not you.

Comment: There must be a problem with the mocha file, i cannot even run it from my win console...

Comment: When you try to run Mocha from the command line, what do you see?

Comment: sorry wrong info, i accidentally entered a wrong path. I get the normal mocha output (about tests) . In Atom the undefined mocha command is still remaining.

Comment: Ok i have installed mocha now in my project locally, i get a different error message (even the mocha command still remains undefined) the error is `'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file`

Comment: Where is that error coming from?

Comment: also from the atom mocha test runner package

Comment: Try `node -v` from both your console and `process-palette`. Programs run by Atom packages will generally inherit Atom's environment variables, which may be different from what a generic new shell has.

Answer (score 1):

Still having no idea about why the package isn't working, I'm going to give a cop-out answer. If we figure out how to make it work, you can accept that answer instead. [`process-palette`](https://atom.io/packages/process-palette) gives you the ability to run highly specific command-line instructions from Atom commands. Here's an example of a command that runs `mocha` in the project path for the current file with the same hotkey and also conveniently organized into its own menu item:

[image: A Process Palette command configuration view.]

The disadvantage of this approach is that you have to know how to use the external program yourself. Packages like `mocha-test-runner` are designed to remove that need from the user, but as we can see here, sometimes the package doesn't know what it needs to be doing. The disadvantage is mitigated by the fact that you only have to learn the command for long enough to set up the configuration to run it, and from that point on it's very easy.

Advantages versus other packages include the ability to *precisely* control what's going on. Say you have multiple top-level folders in the current project, and they have different test suites. A package like `mocha-test-runner` can get the path from the active file, or from the project. If the developer chose to grab the project path, then you're going to have trouble running individual test suites. With the configuration I've shared, the command will always be run in the absolute path of the current file's project folder, so the tests will be run for whichever file you're working on at the time.

Comment: I appreciate the alternate solution but i don't understand howto setup this process-pallette for mocha (my test command is `BABEL_ENV=dev npm run mocha-test`) which is (`"mocha-test": "mocha --recursive tests/mocha"`)

Comment: Just change the command to `npm run mocha-test`, scroll down to the section for environment variables, and add `BABEL_ENV` there.

Comment: i have found an alternate test-runner which is working: https://github.com/boogie666/atom-mocha, i let this question open awhile, if no one has a solution then i accept your answer as the only possible workaround